# Ant design Pro Table saving Table Settings

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

İs there any way to save ant design pro table *Table Settings* ? For example ı am unclicking one column or moving one column to upper, but when ı refresh the page Table Settings are resetting.
[U can see image from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJOb9.png)

How can ı reach this table states ? maybe if ı reach i can save it in localstorage. İs there any ideas about this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.